# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, backend

I am trying to use context API to fetch users from my backend. My api calls are working in Postman, but when I try to console log dispatch it returns undefined. I tried taking help from a similar context api call for movies which works, but duplicating the code led to the same error.

Below are the codes for my context API:

apiCalls.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  updateUserStart,
  createUserFailure,
  updateUserSuccess,
  updateUserFailure,
  createUserStart,
  createUserSuccess,
  deleteUserFailure,
  deleteUserStart,
  deleteUserSuccess,
  getUsersFailure,
  getUsersStart,
  getUsersSuccess,
} from "./UserActions";

export const getUsers = async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(getUsersStart());
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/users/", {
      headers: {
        token: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).accessToken,
      },
    });
    dispatch(getUsersSuccess(res.data));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(getUsersFailure());
  }
};

//create
export const createUser = async (user, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(createUserStart());
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("/users/", user, {
      headers: {
        token: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).accessToken,
      },
    });
    dispatch(createUserSuccess(res.data));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(createUserFailure());
  }
};

//update
export const updateUser = async (id, user, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(updateUserStart());
  try {
    await axios.put(`/users/${id}`, user, {
      headers: {
        token: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).accessToken,
      },
    });
    dispatch(updateUserSuccess(user));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(updateUserFailure());
  }
};

//delete
export const deleteUser = async (id, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(deleteUserStart());
  try {
    await axios.delete("/users/" + id, {
      headers: {
        token: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).accessToken,
      },
    });
    dispatch(deleteUserSuccess(id));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(deleteUserFailure());
  }
};
```

UserContext.js

```
import UserReducer from "./UserReducer";
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  users: [],
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};

export const UserContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(UserReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        users: state.users,
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

UserActions.js

```
export const getUsersStart = () => ({
  type: "GET_USERS_START",
});

export const getUsersSuccess = (users) => ({
  type: "GET_USERS_SUCCESS",
  payload: users,
});

export const getUsersFailure = () => ({
  type: "GET_USERS_FAILURE",
});

export const createUserStart = () => ({
  type: "CREATE_USER_START",
});

export const createUserSuccess = (user) => ({
  type: "CREATE_USER_SUCCESS",
  payload: user,
});

export const createUserFailure = () => ({
  type: "CREATE_USER_FAILURE",
});

export const updateUserStart = () => ({
  type: "UPDATE_USER_START",
});

export const updateUserSuccess = (user) => ({
  type: "UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS",
  payload: user,
});

export const updateUserFailure = () => ({
  type: "UPDATE_USER_FAILURE",
});

export const deleteUserStart = () => ({
  type: "DELETE_USER_START",
});

export const deleteUserSuccess = (id) => ({
  type: "DELETE_USER_SUCCESS",
  payload: id,
});

export const deleteUserFailure = () => ({
  type: "DELETE_USER_FAILURE",
});
```

UserReducer.js

```
const UserReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_USERS_START":
      return {
        users: [],
        isFetching: true,
        error: false,
      };
    case "GET_USERS_SUCCESS":
      return {
        users: action.payload,
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case "GET_USERS_FAILURE":
      return {
        users: [],
        isFetching: false,
        error: true,
      };
    case "CREATE_USER_START":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
        error: false,
      };
    case "CREATE_USER_SUCCESS":
      return {
        users: [...state.users, action.payload],
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case "CREATE_USER_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: true,
      };
    case "UPDATE_USER_START":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
        error: false,
      };
    case "UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS":
      return {
        users: state.users.map(
          (user) => user._id === action.payload._id && action.payload
        ),
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case "UPDATE_USER_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: true,
      };
    case "DELETE_USER_START":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
        error: false,
      };
    case "DELETE_USER_SUCCESS":
      return {
        users: state.users.filter((user) => user._id !== action.payload),
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case "DELETE_USER_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: true,
      };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

export default UserReducer;
```

Below is the component in which I have used my context API:

UserList.jsx

```
import "./userList.css";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { DeleteOutline } from "@mui/icons-material";
// import { userRows } from "../../dummyData";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../../context/userContext/UserContext";
import { deleteUser, getUsers } from "../../context/userContext/apiCalls";

export default function UserList() {
  const { users, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);  

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers(dispatch);
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    deleteUser(id, dispatch);
  };
  
  const columns = [
    { field: "_id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
    {
      field: "user",
      headerName: "User",
      width: 200,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <div className="userListUser">
            <img className="userListImg" src={params.row.profilePic} alt="" />
            {params.row.username}
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
    { field: "email", headerName: "Email", width: 200 },
    {
      field: "isAdmin",
      headerName: "isAdmin",
      width: 120,
    },
    {
      field: "createdAt",
      headerName: "Joining Date",
      width: 160,
    },
    {
      field: "action",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 150,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Link
              to={{ pathname: "/user/" + params.row._id, user: params.row}} state ={{user: users.filter((user) => user._id===params.row._id)}} 
            >
              <button className="userListEdit">Edit</button>
            </Link>
            <DeleteOutline
              className="userListDelete"
              onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row._id)}
            />
          </>
        );
      },
    },
  ];  
  return (
    <div className="userList">
      <div>
        <DataGrid
          rows={users}
          disableSelectionOnClick
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={8}
          checkboxSelection
          getRowId={(user) => user._id}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );    
}
```

When I go to the /users page I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function
    at getUsers (apiCalls.js:18:1)
    at main.14e3e9da176b2c7111d3.hot-update.js:45:76
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26935:1).
```

I have tried calling dispatch in every possible way, but my users prop just keeps returning an empty array. Please do help me out if possible and feel free to ask more resources if you need it.

Comment: Why did you add the [activation-context-api] tag?

Comment: What does `console.log(context)` return ?